# Browser back leaves page after going fullscreen in stack snippet

Tags: feature-request, stack-snippets

Opening a Stack Snippet in full screen should use `history.pushState()` to add an entry to the browser history stack. Clicking back will then close the snippet rather than leave the page completely.

Comment: Executing the snippet already uses `pushState()`, so when using the back button you aren't leaving the question, instead there's [a bug](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/239613/167646), the "full screen" modal isn't closed.

Comment: The functionality I observed was the browser going back to the previous page. Ill test again when I'm not on mobile.