# Clicking back button after entering full screen

Tags: bug, stack-snippets

I'm clicking `Run code snipped`, then `Full page` and then the back button in my browser. And now I get a white blank page with only `Close` button.

Expected results: the full screen should close and the page should get back to the question/answer.

Testcase: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/239465/270836